# React scroll event doesn't stop firing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, react-hooks, dom-events

At work we're having some performance issues with rendering data tables so we've decided to try to virtualize a list "window". Essentially following the same idea as [react-window](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-window), whereby you only render the sublist - the one showing on your viewport - of your data list.

For a myriad of reasons, we tried to implement the technique ourselves. In doing so, we learnt this is mostly done using `position: absolute` on each list item, which didn't really suitable for us. So we came up with the idea of just having two "wrapper" divs around the sublist we want to render.
Essentially box1 would have the height equal to the combined height of all the list items before our window and box2 would have the height of all the items after our window. Every time the user scrolls, we figure out which indices to render and adjust the box heights.

Unfortunately we ran into an issue where, when the user scrolls down, the scroll event keeps firing even after the user has stopped scrolling. This scrolls the list all the way to the end. It seems to work fine when scrolling up though, so we're really at a loss here. We couldn't figure out why it keeps firing.

[Here's a link to an example](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-playground-forked-lfz7i?file=/src/index.js). I just replaced all the list item logic with a fixed box for simplicity. I've also added a timeout to the scroll handler so the scrolling up behaviour is more noticeable, otherwise it's too fast and the red upper box is not noticeable.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

EDIT: We're actually using this in a `<table>` element, which means solutions based on css `position` property will not work, given that that property has undefined behaviour for table elements, and it breaks the standard table layout.

Comment: May I know why `react-window` didn't work for you? Also have you tried `react-virtualized` list?

Comment: The main reason is both libs rely on `position: absolute` which has undefined behaviour for html <table> elements. 
They also force you to use their own components which add extra html that clashes with our hierarchy and style guide. It further relies on the functions-as-child pattern, which we consider to be a bad pattern, although we can work around that. 
It's a common problem with react libs, where behaviour is exposed via component/html rather than being view agnostic. React-table is an example of what I look for in libs.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely caused by using the scrollTop value to change the height of the items which cause the scrollTop value to change and so on (maybe).

Here is the right way to do it https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-playground-forked-97vsq

```
import React, { useState, useCallback } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const ROW_HEIGHT = 25;

const App = (props) => {
  const [items, innerHeight, onScroll] = useVirtualizedList({
    numItems: 500,
    itemHeight: ROW_HEIGHT,
    windowHeight: ROW_HEIGHT * 5,
    windowExtension: 0
  });
  return (
    <div onScroll={onScroll} style={{ height: "500px", overflowY: "scroll" }}>
      <div style={{
        // position should be calculated depanding on the parent element position
        position: 'fixed'
      }}>{items}</div>
      <div className="forceOverflow" style={{height: 500 * ROW_HEIGHT}}></div>
    </div>
  );
};


const useVirtualizedList = ({ numItems, itemHeight, windowHeight }) => {
  const [scrollTop, setScrollTop] = useState(0);

  const innerHeight = numItems * itemHeight;
  const startIndex = Math.floor(scrollTop / itemHeight);
  const endIndex = Math.min(
    numItems - 1,
    startIndex + Math.floor( windowHeight / itemHeight)
  );

  const onScroll = useCallback((e) => {
    const currentScroll = e.currentTarget.scrollTop;
    setScrollTop(currentScroll);
  }, []);

  const items = `${startIndex} --- ${endIndex}`

  return [items, innerHeight, onScroll];
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: @tiansivive making a scroll bar with HTML and CSS would be better I think, this way you wouldn't need to set position

Comment: The problem there is you're relying on using css `position`, which doesn't work for us since this has to be applied to a <table> element. Positioning seems to have undefined behaviour for table elements according to the spec and keeps breaking the table layout.
Perhaps I should have been clearer about that in the question. I'll edit it.

So the scroll top property changes if a child gets resized, event if the total height remains the same? it doesn't make much sense to me 

Comment: I suppose a custom made scroll bar could be a good workaround, had not thought of that!