# React scroll event keeps on firing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-functional-component

I'm working on a react functional components project, wherein I've to increment scroll position programmatically when a user actually scrolls in a div.

*for example*, I've a div with id `testDiv` & a user scrolled down a bit, now the scroll position is 100, so I want to programmatically increment it by 1 and make it 101.

**Problem statement:** The scroll position keeps on incrementing via `onScroll` handler, so the scrollbar only stops at the end of the element even if we scroll only once.

**Expected behaviour:** Scroll position should be incremented only once by the `onScroll` handler if we scroll once on the UI.

**What I tried:** (dummy code for the reproduction purpose)

```
import React, { useCallback } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
    
const App = (props) => {
  const onScroll = useCallback((event) => {
    const section = document.querySelector('#testDiv');
    // **The problem is here, scrollTop keeps on incrementing even if we scrolled only once**
    if (section) section.scrollTop = event.scrollTop + 1;
  }, []);
  
  return (
    <div id="testDiv" onScroll={onScroll} style={{ height: "500px", overflowY: "scroll" }}>
      <div>test</div>
      <div className="forceOverflow" style={{height: 500 * 25}}></div>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: I've also found and tried the answer to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67169140/react-scroll-event-doesnt-stop-firing) with no luck!

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is throttling or debouncing the function. It keeps on incrementing because with every bit of scroll, `onScroll` is being called.

There are many ways to throttle functions in react but I like to use debounce from lodash. If I remember correctly it was about 1.5kb gzipped.

I made you a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-ride-fd1rl?file=/src/App.js). And here is the code:

```
import React, { useCallback } from "react";
import _debounce from "lodash/debounce";

export const App = (props) => {
  let debouncedOnScroll = useCallback(
    _debounce(() => {
      // YOUR CODE HERE
      console.log("CHECK THE CONSOLE TO SEE HOW MANY TIMES IT'S GETTING CALLED");
    }, 150), []); // Wait 150ms to see if I'm being called again, if I got called before 150ms, don't run me!

  return (
    <div
      id="testDiv"
      onScroll={debouncedOnScroll}
      style={{ height: "500px", overflowY: "scroll" }}
    >
      <div>test</div>
      <div className="forceOverflow" style={{ height: 500 * 25 }}></div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

By the way, use `useRef` API instead of `document.querySelector`. This query selector is getting called with every scroll and it's not the lightest weight on the client computer.

Comment: Even if I increment scrollbar position programmatically in the debounce function, it do call onScroll again & it goes increasing untill the scroll goes at the bottom.